# Why use org-mobile-push/pull?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, gtd

I have managed my todo-lists for some years with Emacs Org-mode and really like it. 
The files are kept in a WebDAV folder on a server to keep them synced.
However, since I use more and more tablets and smartphones an app to access the files would be great - such as MobileOrg for Android.

But currently I do not understand why I have to use org-mobile-push and pull in emacs and cannot just parse and access my files with an app and edit them in a convenient way, especially when I am a few days not working with Emacs or at my Linux machine at all. Is there a reasonable explanation why the files can't be parsed and viewed without exporting them from Emacs?

Comment: My three guesses, in no particular order, would be 1)Encryption mechanism 2)Avoid race conditions between edits and 3)Simplify code running in the device (stuff like creating agenda).  But those are only guesses... probably the developers could provide a much better explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MobileOrg needs to interact with Emacs through a directory on a server. The main reason for `org-mobile.el` to exist is for creating agenda views in a format that can be displayed by MobileOrg, and for integrating notes captured and changes made by MobileOrg back into your Emacs main system. That said, the functions `org-mobile-push` and `org-mobile-pull` are purely there to provide a sync mechanism between MobileOrg and your Emacs main system. There is nothing technically stopping you from doing your own parsing and editing the of the files. I suppose that you only have to ensure that the files remain valid Org-Mode file formats and they should work everywhere.